# Document Previews in Browser

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, preview

Is there some way to preview documents in browser?  Specifically in say an iframe within a page, as opposed to opening the doc in a new tab?  I have a list of files of any type and when a user clicks on one, want to open it in a readonly format.  If that file is a video or audio file, that's easy enough, but I'd like to be able to also do pdfs, word docs, maybe excel.  Preferably it would be in a cross browser friendly way but if I need to do detection for a plugin (I've seen Google Docs Viewer for FF) I can live with that.

**UPDATE:**

ShaneC's answer is great and will work well in general.  The one hitch I see is that for html5 devices (think ipad), I need to convert the document into a series of images.  Is there any way for me to do this in an automated fashion?  I need to be able to do this automatically when a new document is uploaded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to integrate a cross-browser cross-type document viewer. Google will give you some good sites, personally I've had good experiences with [Flex Paper](http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/).

For demos, see here: http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/demo/

Comment: That looks totally awesome.  I'll give it a test run.

Comment: Be sure to take a look at the HTML5 implementation. I haven't used that flavor yet, but it looks really promising (considering devices like the iPad).

Comment: @Endophage : That is a whole-nother ball of wax. You'll neeed to use PHP (or another dynamic language) to iterate through the document and then create images of it. I've no experience doing this personally, so you might be better off asking a new question with updated tags. I can, however, recommend you look into something like this: [PHP.NET Resource on PDF](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php) ; [A question thread where it seems someone got a resolution on a similar question](http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=230074)

Answer (score 4):

There is the Javascript [ViewerJs.](http://viewerjs.org/) An open source tool which allows a website to display PDF and open standard for office documents. It will display the documents inline and without browser plugins.

Answer (score 4):

There is another approach that can be used to view images/pdf/xlsx/docx etc.

You can use iframe and google's gview in the following way:

```js
 const YOUR_URL = https://calibre-ebook.com/downloads/demos/demo.docx;
 
 <iframe
   className="doc"
   src={`https://docs.google.com/gview?url=${YOUR_URL}&embedded=true`}
 />
```